# How to list all folders on specified drives with folder name first then gap then full path to folder?

Tags: cmd, directory

```
dir i:\ j:\ k:\ /b /s /a:-D >c:\Users\Jason\Desktop\allFolderFilesOn_I_J_K.txt
```

This works great, but I am after a custom output, `foldername full_path`

Is this possible and if so how do I achieve this?

Comment: take a look to `for /?` and note especially the modifiers `~...`

Comment: I am still none the wiser.  Please can you provide some links to example of use as I have tried to find site using such phrases as.
Using for with dir in dos
dos directories using for

but nothing is making sense

Comment: on command line enter `for %a in (*) do @echo %~dpa %~fa`. Also read the output of `for /?` to learn, why and how it works.

Comment: OK, I now realise it is a command of its own, I thought you added this in another command.  But can not get this right, been playing around with various combinations and now got this.

Comment: OK, I now realise it is a command of its own, I thought you added this in another command.  I tried the suggestion but it showed the folder path and file name.  Been playing around with various combinations and now got this.

for %a in (*) do @echo %~nxa %~dpa

But this give me the file name then the path to the file.  I am after only folders not files.  Foldername then the path to the folder.  But for all drives but just the current directory.

Comment: don't understand. Give an example ([edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51474700/edit) your question accordingly)

Comment: My question is still the same.  But to give example of output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't want any files, but for every folder instead of `C:\windows\system32` you want an output like `system32  C:\Windows\`

This can be done with the following command:

```
(for /d /r "D:\" %a in (*) do @echo %~nxa %~dpa)>c:\Users\Jason\Desktop\allFolderFilesOn_I_J_K.txt
```

where `/d` means "Directories only"
`/r` "Recursive" ("down the folder tree")
`"D:\"` the starting point
`%~nxa` the last element (the folder name)
`%~dpa` the drive/path to the folder

Note: this is command line syntax. For use in a batch file, replace each `%` with `%%`